# Why two of my different sql queries that must perform the same result act different?

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, count, date-arithmetic

I need to get the number of new buyers who came in 1990 year.
The first query says it's 17, but the second says it's 29? So which one is wrong and why?

```
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(customer_id) FROM SALES_ORDER WHERE
EXTRACT(YEAR FROM order_date) = 1990
AND
customer_id NOT IN (SELECT customer_id FROM SALES_ORDER WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM order_date) < 1990);
```

```
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(customer_id) FROM SALES_ORDER WHERE
customer_id IN (SELECT customer_id FROM SALES_ORDER WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM order_date) = 1990)
AND
customer_id NOT IN (SELECT customer_id FROM SALES_ORDER WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM order_date) < 1990);
```

Here is my data schema:
[image]

Comment: Perhaps you want `count(distinct...)` not `distinct count(...)`

Comment: @jjanes you are right, maybe post it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both queries do not do what you want. You are using `SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(customer_id)`, while you probably want `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT customer_id)`.

I find that the logic would be simpler expressed with two levels of aggregation:

```
select count(*)
from (
    select customer_id
    from sales_order
    group by customer_id
    having extract(year from min(order_date)) = 1990
) t
```